# An alternative approach to timers to handle realtime simulations with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, real-time, setinterval, simulation

I am playing around with this simple prototype to run a mass of simulations (in this case let us say a simple game) in realtime.

I can not imagine that it is best practice to run thausands of timers serverside. So does there exsits an alternative to timers to run a big count of simulations in node.js in realtime?

I could imagine to process a staple of commands but I dont know how to ensure / scale  that a tick has a duration of let us say one minute.

```
var Events = require("events");

var Game = function(tickspeed) {
    this.tickspeed = tickspeed || 100;
    return this;
};


Game.prototype = new Events.EventEmitter();

var i = 0;
Game.prototype.tick = function() {
    //this.timer
    this.emit("tick", {});
    if (i>100) this.stop();
};

Game.prototype.start = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.startTime = new Date();

    setTimeout(function() {
        self.timer = setInterval(function(){
            self.tick();
        }, self.tickspeed);
        self.emit("start", {game : self});
    }, self.tickspeed);
};

Game.prototype.stop = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.endTime = new Date();
    clearTimeout(self.timer);
};


module.exports = Game;
```

Comment: This is quite a broad or opinion based topic, so isn't best suited to Stack Overflow.  Also - you mention best practices - some people might argue that using node.js on a server for running simulations _at all_ is a best practice - other languages that uses multiple threads and aren't designed to be event driven may be more suited.

Comment: I do not agree. The question points to parallel realtime processes without timers in node.js. not an ideology discussion.

Comment: *"So what strategy might be the best"* directly asks for an opinion.

Comment: Sorry I dont wanted to make a science of it. I have changed the question.

Comment: This question is interesting, i don't see why it's closed, he changed the question anyways...